# How to exclude debug javascript from rails 3 application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some debug javascript functions defined in my rails 3 application under /app/assets/javascripts/debug.js. Is there any trivial way to ensure that these are only included for development, not test or production environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for any of:

- `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`
- `RAILS_ENV`
- `Rails.env`
- `Rails.env.development?`